# Correcting javascript to align with html a href

Tags: javascript, html

My single page website is not functioning.  i connected it to the list through an a href but my website is still not coming up. I am trying to duplicate in my own way through coding the below codepen

https://codepen.io/bassta/pen/Eicla?editors=1111  please help if you can.

```html
 <html> <head>   <script>$(function() {

//Image by Ivaylo Yovchev (  http://ivayloyovchev.com/weddings )
  
 //elements
 var $menu = $(".menu");
 var $pages = $(".page");
 var $menuLi = $menu.find("li").not(".to-home");
 var $toHome = $menu.find(".to-home");
 
 //interna vars
 var currentPage = "";
 
 $toHome.on("click", function() {
  currentPage = "";
  TweenMax.to($pages, 0.5, {
   left: "-70%"
  });
  TweenLite.to($menuLi.filter(".active"), 0.5, {
   className: "-=active"
  });
 });
 
 $menuLi.on("click", function(event) {
  
  var $this = $(this);
  var thisHref = $this.find("a").attr("href");
  
  if (currentPage !== thisHref && $pages.filter(thisHref).length > 0) {
   currentPage = thisHref;
   TweenMax.to($pages, 0.5, {
    left: "-70%"
   });
   TweenMax.to($pages.filter(thisHref), 0.5, {
    left: 0
   });
   TweenLite.to($menuLi.filter(".active"), 0.5, {
    className: "-=active"
   });
   TweenLite.to($this, 0.5, {
    className: "+=active"
   });
  }
  
  event.preventDefault();
 });
});</script><style>

ul  {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  list-style: none;
}
ol {list-style:none;
width:200px;
    
}
ul li {
  box-shadow: 6px 6px 2px 1px #FFEF99;
  border-radius: 5px;
  float: right;
  width: 240px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: black;
  opacity: .4;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-right: 8px;
}

ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: gold;
}

ul li a:hover {
  background-color: red;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

ul li ul li {
  display: none;
}

ul li:hover ul li {
  display: block;
}

.page{
  background-color:red;
  
}
.page-content{background-color:red;}

</style> </head><body><ul>

              <li style="width: 140px;"><a href="#Home">Home</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li style="width: 140px;"><a href="#Product">Product</a>
        <ul>
          <li style="width: 140px;"><a href="Product1">Product1</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li style="width: 140px;"><a href="Comb">Comb</a>
        <ul>
          <li style="width: 140px;"><a a href="Lorem"></a>Lorem</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <ul>
        <li style="width: 140px;"><a a href="Brush">Brush</a>
          <ul>
            <li style="width: 140px;"><a a href="Clip">Clip</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
         <ul>
      <li style="width: 140px;"><a href="Contact Us">Contact Us</a>
        <ul>
         <li style="width: 140px;"><a  href="About us">About Us</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <ul>
        <li style="width: 140px;"><a href="Testimonials">Testimonials</a>
          <ul>
           <li style="width: 140px;"><a href="Terms"></a></li>
          </ul>
        </li> 
        <div id="aboutus" class="page">
        <div class="page-content">
            <h2>Lorem</h2>

            <p>lorem</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="gallery" class="page">
        <div class="page-content">
            <h2>"Neque porro quisquam</h2>

            <p> dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit..."
"There is no one who loves pain itself, who seeks after it and wants to have it, simply because it is pain..."
What is Lorem Ipsum?
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to </p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="Product" class="page">
        <div class="page-content">
            <h2>est qui dolorem ipsum quia </h2>

            <p>make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="Contactus" class="page">
        <div class="page-content">
            <h2>Contacts</h2>

            <p>Some contact form</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    </body> </html>
```

My single page website is not functioning.  i connected it to the list through an a href but my website is still not coming up. I am trying to duplicate in my own way through coding the below codepen

Comment: like @Sv443 said, you are missing js libraries. the CodePen is using //cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js and https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/latest/TweenMax.min.js

Answer (score 0):

As indicated by the error message `ReferenceError: $ is not defined` you haven't included the jQuery script. Make sure to put this tag in your <head> and also before any script tag that uses jQuery:
`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: I then tried it on this site and it still doesn't hide the text http://jsfiddle.net/rissa146/v6bxurdo/29/

Comment: It still isn't in the `<head>`